# How to throw inside a closure in a function?

Tags: swift, closures, throw

I'm refactoring my code to make everything cleaner. I make request to my API and can expect different types of returning values so I created a generic function to simplify my code.

I wanted this function to throw so I could simply use `do catch` to handle error or success case with different types.

This is my function:

```
func performRequest<T: Codable>(_ request: URLRequest, ofType: T.Type) throws -> T{
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, err) in
        if let err = err {throw err}
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if response.statusCode != 200 {
                // Here I would return the value
            } else {
                // here I would throw the error
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

But at the first line after `URLSession.shared.dataTask` I got this error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

I understand that's because I'm trying to throw inside dataTask function, but my question is, is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot `throw` inside the completion handler of `URLSession.shared.dataTask` because the type of that completion handler is already defined and it is not a `throws` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call is asynchronus. You need to return data within closure after data are received. For checking if call succeeded or not you can use newly introduced `Result` type, so you don't need to `throw`

```
func performRequest<T: Codable>(_ request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
        if let err = err {
            return completion(Result.failure(err))
        }
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if response.statusCode == 200 { // 200 is code for OK btw
                return completion(Result.success(someValueOfTypeT))
            } else {
                return completion(Result.failure(yourError))
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Usage: (note that type of `T` can be inferred from closure declaring)

```
performRequest(someRequest) { (result: Result<SomeTypeConformsToCodable, Error>) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):
        // work with value
    case .failure(let err):
        print(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Robert Dresler thank you very much for your answer, I've tried this approach of using throwing function because I call this function inside another function that also takes a completionHandler with parameter of Result type, so I thought throwing would be cleaner to read once I would have to send the Result inside another Result, now I realise that's the way to go... thank you